# Query Percona Cluster Nodes For Current Load

Tags: php, mysql, cluster-computing, percona

I'm attempting to put together a mysql load balancer with a mockup php like script. Problem is i've been looking about countless variables in the database and cant find a variable of the current load on that server so I can pick the faster server to give the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mysql is not aware of the server resource use, so what to do is to use for example Cacti, get the data from there and use that in your loadbalancing app.

Another way is just to use round robin and assume the systems will be pretty normally distributed over time.

Third option is to auto scale the number of slave servers using for example Kubernetes with NFS & ZFS for central storage and making snapshots of the database available on the slave nodes (for a read only solution